# Next.js rendering pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

If I have a market like application with page of products list, what rendering type will be better choice in this situation? Does Static Generation update the list after refreshing the page?

Comment: **Next.js rendering pages**, is that a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, SSG(static-site-generation) will fetch the data and generate the pages at build time with all the static assets. Which means the list will not update after refreshing the page.

From nextjs [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended),

> If a page uses Static Generation, the page HTML is generated at build time. That means in production, the page HTML is generated when you run next build . This HTML will then be reused on each request. It can be cached by a CDN.

If you have incremental data requirements you to do either server-side-rendering with data fetching method `getServerSideProps` or can use client-side data-fetching with something like [`swr`](https://github.com/vercel/swr) or [`react-query`](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query)

Comment: though nextjs supports on-demand ssg using fallback pages, see https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#fallback-false